# Need a login for a cordova based app

Tags: cordova, session, cookies, authentication, oauth-2.0

I currently was building on my cordova app and the last piece missing to complete the app is a login. I want the user to be able to type in his username and pw and he than should get redirected on a html page in my cordova app. In this page he gets shown his information. To achieve that i would need a login with cookies or sessions. (I would need the cookies or sessions to work on multible pages) So i tried using OAuth2 but somehow i am not able to redirect to the html page after a successfull login. Does anbody know how i can redirect onto the html page or does anybody know a tutorial where i can make this happen?

Comment: show what you have done,here.

Comment: Sorry for the late respanse, I was busy in the last couple of days. What I coded til now, are several html files with a lot of code in it so i wont be able to post all of it. But I will however post an example where i would need to userID that i only show a certain user his information.

Answer (score 1):

So here is one of the codes where i would need to UserID so i only can show a ceratin user his information, in this cases the routes he drove in the last couple of days. The routes are saved in a database (together with the user ID ofc)

```
function dataRequest() {
        document.getElementById("checkbox2").checked = false;
        document.getElementById("checkbox3").checked = false;
        var output = $('#output').text('Loading data...');
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://80.120.42.246:7781/html/getmeineFahrten.php',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
            timeout: 5000,
            success: function(data, status){

                output.empty();

                var ort = '<div>'+'<table border="1" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-responsive">'+
                    '<thead>'+
                        '<tr>'+
                        '<th>Abfahrtszeitpunkt</th>'+
                        '<th>Retourfahrt</th>'+
                        '<th>Startort</th>'+'<th>Zielort</th>'+
                        '<th>Karte</th>'+
                        '<th>Bewertung</th>'+
                        '</tr>'+
                    '</head>'
                // table col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-8 table-striped table-bordered table-responsive
               $.each(data, function(i,item){
                var ServerDatum = item.abfahrt
                var Datumonly = ServerDatum.substring(0,4) + ServerDatum.substring(5,7) + ServerDatum.substring(8,10);
                var calcDatum = Datum - Datumonly
                if(item.user_user_id == userID){
                if(calcDatum < 0){
                if(! item.durch){
                    item.durch = "keine Bewertung";
                };

                var fahrt = JSON.parse(item.fahrten_id);
                ort += '<tbody>'+ 
                            '<tr>'+'<td>'+item.abfahrt+'</td>' 
                                    +'<td>'+item.rueckfahrt+'</td>' 
                                    + '<td>'+item.StartOrt+'</td>'
                                    + '<td>'+item.ZielOrt+'</td>'
                                    +'<td>'+'<div id="button_style">'+'<button name="Map" type="button" onclick=initialize('+fahrt+')>'+ '<img src="http://80.120.42.246:7781/Graphics/map.png" width="40" height="40">'+'</div>'+'</td>'
                                    + '<td>'+item.durch+'</td>' 
                            +'</tr>';
                + '</tbody>'+
                '</div>'


                }
                }
                });
                                ort += '</table>';
                                output.append(ort);

            },
            error: function(){
                output.text('There was an error loading the data.');
                navigator.notification.confirm(
                    'Something went wrong. Would you like to retry?',
                    yourCallback,
                   'Error',
                    'No,Yes'
                );
            }
        });
    }
```

So this is the complete Ajax request and right now I am controlling it via hardcode:

```
if(item.user_user_id == userID){
```

What i would like to do is, to have the userID from the database of the logged in user. Right now i have userID hardcoded as 1 coded in the script.